# Error in finding dynamic created control

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, file-upload, dynamic-controls

I am uploading images using Fileupload control and after loading the file when I click Upload button the file will be saved in a folder in server, but before saving into database I need to add Image description along with the image.. But I dont know I am getting some error. I am able to save file in folder but when I save it into database only one dynamic added control wil be found and then it will give **Object reference not set to instance of object** Even though there are more than one controls in that particular div. Before going into code I will tell what controls I am adding after I upload the file.. I am adding one image control and textbox for each of the image files I uploaded.. When I upload only one file it will simply go into the foreach loop once again after 1st time.. My code might explain it more.

So this is my .aspx code:

```
<form id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <div class="transbox" id="mainbk" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" >
      <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="UploadImages" style="background-color:white; position:absolute; font-family:'Palatino Linotype'; font-size:medium; top: 4px; left: 350px; right: 251px;" Width="500px" AllowMultiple="true"/>

        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="uploadedFile" style="position:absolute;  font-family:'Palatino Linotype'; font-size:medium; top: 4px; left: 870px; width: 112px; height: 29px;" Text="Upload" OnClick="uploadFile_Click" />
        <asp:Panel ID="updtpanel" runat="server" CssClass="transbox" style="width:100%;height:100%;left:0px;top:0px;position:absolute" Visible="false">
             <asp:Button ID="btnsave" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="true" Text="Save" OnClick="btnsave_Click" Font-Bold="true" BackColor="Yellow"></asp:Button>

        </asp:Panel>
     </div>


    </form>
```

and this is my backend code.

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
SqlDataReader reader;
int id = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string filepath = "";
string newpath = "";
int tid = 0;
int count = 0;
int cnt1 = 0;
string textid = "";
Panel dload;
Image img;
TextBox ta;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    con.Open();
    com = new SqlCommand("select max(slid) from slider", con);
    reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            id = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetInt32(0));
        }
    }
    con.Close();
    com.Dispose();
    HtmlGenericControl dh = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    dh.Attributes.Add("class", "head");
    dh.InnerText = "Write Description";
    updtpanel.Controls.Add(dh);
    foreach (HttpPostedFile upld in UploadImages.PostedFiles)
    {
        createImgPanel();
    }
}



protected void uploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (UploadImages.HasFiles)
    {
       string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(UploadImages.FileName).ToLower();
       if (fileExt == ".jpeg" || fileExt == ".png" || fileExt == ".jpg" || fileExt == ".bmp")
       {
           foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in UploadImages.PostedFiles)
           {
               count += 1;
               filepath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/Gallery/" + uploadedFile.FileName);
               uploadedFile.SaveAs(filepath);
               newpath = "../Images/Gallery/" + uploadedFile.FileName;
               try
               {
                   Image nimg = dload.FindControl("img" + count) as Image;
                   nimg.ImageUrl = newpath.ToString();
               }

               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   Response.Write(ex.Message);
               }

           }
       }
       else
       {
           Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('Please Select only Image Files!!');", true);
       }

    }
    else
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('Please Select a File First!!');", true);        
    }
}

public void createImgPanel()
{
    tid = tid + 1;
    textid = "txt" + tid;
    ta = new TextBox();
    img = new Image();
    ta.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
    dload = new Panel();
    updtpanel.Visible = true;
    dload.Attributes.Add("class", "dataload");
    //dload.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
    dload.ID = "ind" + tid;
    img.CssClass = "loadimg";

    img.ID = "img" + tid;
    //img.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
    ta.Attributes.Add("class", "txtdes");
    ta.ID = textid;
    //ta.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
    dload.Controls.Add(img);
    dload.Controls.Add(ta);
    updtpanel.Controls.Add(dload);
}

protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {

            Panel pv = (this.Form.FindControl("mainbk").FindControl("updtpanel")) as Panel;

            foreach (Control cd in pv.Controls)
            {
                cnt1 = cnt1 + 1;
                TextBox txt = cd.FindControl("ind" + cnt1).FindControl("txt" + cnt1) as TextBox;****This is where I am getting the above said error****
                Image img = cd.FindControl("ind" + cnt1).FindControl("img" + cnt1) as Image;

                    string str = "";
                    str = txt.Text;
                    string iurl = "";
                    iurl = img.ImageUrl;

                    id += 1;

                    string Insert = "Insert into slider (slid,slurl,slalt) values (@id,@IMAGE_PATH,@alter)";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Insert, con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMAGE_PATH", iurl);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alter", str);
                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();

                    }
                    catch (Exception e1)
                    {
                        Response.Write(e1.Message);
                    }
                }





        updtpanel.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

****I am getting error in the last part of above code i.e. save button click event. For Textbox Find control I am getting error. First Image will be saved successfully but for other images its not finding control even if they are present in the design.****

**I just want to know whether I am committing any mistakes in save click event or is there any mistake in whole coding itself**

**Edit**

So this is the HTML source after the controls are rendered in runtime:

```
    <div id="mainbk" class="transbox" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
          <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="UploadImages" id="UploadImages" style="width:500px;background-color:white; position:absolute; font-family:'Palatino Linotype'; font-size:medium; top: 4px; left: 350px; right: 251px;">

            <input type="submit" name="uploadedFile" value="Upload" id="uploadedFile" style="position:absolute;  font-family:'Palatino Linotype'; font-size:medium; top: 4px; left: 870px; width: 112px; height: 29px;">
            <div id="updtpanel" class="transbox" style="width:100%;height:100%;left:0px;top:0px;position:absolute">

                 <input type="submit" name="btnsave" value="Save" id="btnsave" style="background-color:Yellow;font-weight:bold;">

            <div class="head">Write Description</div><div id="ind1" class="dataload">
            <img id="img1" class="loadimg" runat="server" src="../Images/Gallery/God%201.jpg">
<textarea name="txt1" rows="2" cols="20" id="txt1" class="txtdes"></textarea>
        </div><div id="ind2" class="dataload">
            <img id="img2" class="loadimg" runat="server" src="../Images/Gallery/God%202.jpg">
<textarea name="txt2" rows="2" cols="20" id="txt2" class="txtdes"></textarea>
        </div><div id="ind3" class="dataload">
            <img id="img3" class="loadimg" runat="server" src="../Images/Gallery/God%203.jpg">
<textarea name="txt3" rows="2" cols="20" id="txt3" class="txtdes"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
         </div>
```

**Edited**

K I just went deeper into the exception I am getting... Its saying..

**'((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)(dv)).InnerHtml' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'**

**What does this actually mean.. Its also says that the control is not literal.. What does that mean.. Why its not able to find the control I have appended..** Help me out please..

Comment: FindControl not only search one level but all the control hierarcy. maybe its not the cause of error but it helps making things clear. also you can inspect Request.Form.Keys and see if id of textbox is there.

Comment: @TakeMeAsAGuest.. Say if I have a div and I am including my dynamically added Textbox and Image in that div.. Now if  I use Findcontrols and find those IDs then obviously I should get right.. There are controls present with that right when I see it during runtime.. But findcontrol will not find it... :( Please give me a solution if u knw...

Comment: @TakeMeAsAGuest.. Is it not possible ti inspect the images using Request.Form.Keys.. cs I am able to find the textboxes but not images... :(

Answer (score 0):

add controls in PreRender event, access them at least from PageLoad.

Comment: @TakeMeAsAGuest.. I am loading the controls once again in page_load.. So whenever page loads the controls will be there.. There are 2 cases here:

Case1: If I upload only one file then Image and Textbox regarding to that file will be processed and added.. But here it once again enter into forloop and tries to find the control... which gives error..

Case2: If there are more than one file then also the same case.. It goes in and wont find any control... :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you also include HTML source after it gets render to browser?
What if `cd.FindControl("ind" + cnt1)` returns null in first case?

```
cd.FindControl("ind" + cnt1).FindControl("txt" + cnt1) as TextBox
```

Comment: First case it will not return null..only from 2nd time it will return as object reference not set to an instance of the object... 

By the way u have posted the same code what I have tried... Will you elaborate pls...

Comment: @Amit... I have added the HTML Source after rendering.. Can you get some idea now... :(